Mobile media queries are different from my desktop media queries
For some reason, the positioning is a bit off for my CSS. It works on desktop just fine, but testing it out on my iPad, it looks weird. Could someone point me towards the right direction?
Here is what it looks like on desktop:

Here is what it looks like on my iPad:

Here is the code for everything, sorry there is a lot!


.container {
    font-size: 5px;
    margin-left: 700px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: $white;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding-top: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 
    box-shadow: 30px 30px 1px #e2e2e2;
}

.body {
    width: 330px;
    height: 330px;
    margin-top: 110px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ffa6c9;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 7px rgba(255, 166, 201, 0.4);
    z-index: 1;
}

.left-arm {
    width: 110px;
    height: 210px; 
    border-radius: 2em;
    transform: rotate(-40deg);
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-top: 190px;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 90px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    background: #ffa6c9;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 29px -5px rgba(30, 30, 10, 0.25);
    z-index: 0;
}

.right-arm {
    width: 105px;
    height: 220px;
    border-radius: 2em;
    transform: rotate(-240deg);
    margin-right: 290px;
    margin-top: 230px;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
    background: #ffa6c9;
    z-index: 0;
    animation-name: kirby-wave;
    animation-duration: .8s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(30, 30, 10, 0.2);
}

@keyframes kirby-wave {
    0% {
      top: 10vh;           
    } 
    50% {
      top: 10px;
    }
    100% {
      top: 10vh;
  }
}

.left-leg {
    width: 100px;
    height: 110px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #ff4747;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 400px;
    margin-right: 110px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 75px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 29px -5px rgba(30, 30, 10, 0.55);
}

.right-leg {
    width: 100px;
    height: 110px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #ff4747;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 400px;
    margin-left: 170px;
    transform: rotate(-25deg);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 75px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 29px -5px rgba(30, 30, 10, 0.55);
}

.left-eye {
    width: 45px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: black;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 105px;
}

.right-eye {
    width: 45px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: black;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 105px;
}

.eyes {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.eyeShine {
    width: 25px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 4px #282881;
}

.blueBottom {
    width: 23px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(#00008b, #3232a2, #5a5ab4);
    margin-left: 10.9px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    position: absolute;
}

.mouth {
    width: 42px;
    height: 33px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 13% 13% 50% 50%;
    background: #d80a3e;
}

.tongue {
    width: 20px;
    height: 8px;
    margin-left: 11.2px;
    margin-top: 23px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #ac0831;
    border-radius: 13% 13% 50% 50%;
}

.right-cheek {
    display: inline;
    width: 50px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ff8dba;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 10px #ff8dba;
}

.left-cheek {
    margin-left: 50px;
    display: inline;
    width: 50px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ff8dba;
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 10px #ff8dba;
}

.heart {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffa6f6;
    transform: rotate(225deg);
    margin-left: 1160px;
    margin-top: -290px;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 5px 3px rgba(255, 166, 246, 0.3);
    z-index: 9;
    animation-name: beat;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.heart::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ffa6f6;
    margin-top: 35px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 5px rgba(255, 166, 246, 0.3);
}

.heart::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ffa6f6;
    margin-left: 35px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 5px rgba(255, 166, 246, 0.3);
}

@keyframes beat {
    0% {
      transform: scale(1) rotate(225deg); /* Rotate because I set the degrees of the shape to 225 */
    }
    50% {
      transform: scale(0.7) rotate(225deg);
    }
  }

#kirbyText {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    margin-top: -60px;
    font-size: 120px;
    color: #ffa6c9;
    font-family: 'Comforter', cursive;
}

@media (max-width: 1350px) {
    .container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 170em;
    }

    .right-arm {
        margin-top: 220em;
    }

    .left-arm {
        margin-left: 64em;
    }

    .left-leg {
        margin-right: 20em;
    }

    .right-leg {
        margin-left: 36em;
    }

    .heart {
        margin-left: 160em;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 15em;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 9em;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 5.8em;
    }

    #header {
        width: 160em;
    }
}
<div class="kirby">
            <div class="container">
              <h2 id='kirbyText'>Kirby</h2>
                <div class="body">
                  <div class="eyes">
                  <div class="right-eye">
                    <div class="eyeShine">
                    </div>
                    <div class="blueBottom">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="left-eye">
                    <div class="eyeShine">
                    </div>
                    <div class="blueBottom">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id='cheeks'>
                    <div class="right-cheek"></div>
                    <div class="left-cheek"></div>
                  </div>
                    <div class="mouth">
                    <div class="tongue">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="left-arm">
                </div>
                <div class="right-arm">
                </div>
                <div class="left-leg">
                </div>
                <div class="right-leg">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="heart">
                <div class="beat">
                </div>
              </div> 
        </div>


strong text

Please put a working snippet into your question. For example, we cannot tell what the settings are for wider viewports from what you have given us. An what assumptions are you making about the setting for an em?

Okay, I think I got it in my question.
